# Sample File is part of validating queries/ Power BI adds steps that ruin dataflow

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, google-cloud-dataflow

When saving dataflow Power BI validates Sample File and adds steps - Convert to table, Remove columns, cause it does not support type binary I assume but I don't want it to be validated it's just Helper querie. I don't know where the  issue is. Please help.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxU1X.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hdBG.png)

Comment: Exactly how does PQ `ruin dataflow`? Where do you see a validation step? Where is the copy of your code and data?